# How to use/compile this file?

Tags: c, unix, makefile

I was given this example file called `pMakefile` and I am unsure how to execute it. What command would be used and how it would be used?

I have tried to compile using make and it seems different from a regular makefile. I am using a UNIX environment for this.

```
wombat aardvark.o manatee.o penguin.o velociraptor.o wombat.o [gcc -o 
wombat aardvark.o manatee.o penguin.o velociraptor.o wombat.o]
aardvark.o aardvark.h aardvark.c [gcc -c aardvark.c]
aardvark.h aardvark1.txt aardvark2.txt [date | sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/g' | 
cat -s aardvark1.txt - aardvark2.txt > aardvark.h]
manatee.o manatee.h manatee.c [gcc -c manatee.c]
penguin.o penguin.h penguin.c [gcc -c penguin.c]
velociraptor.o velociraptor.h velociraptor.c [gcc -c velociraptor.c]
wombat.o aardvark.h manatee.h penguin.h velociraptor.h wombat.h wombat.c 
[gcc -c wombat.c]
```

Just want to know how to use the file. executing using:

```
make -f pMakefile gives
pMakefile:1: *** Missing separator. Stop
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a makefile to me.

Comment: Escape the newline using backslash (\\).

Comment: Definitely not a makefile.  It won't work with make.  You'll have to ask the person who gave it to you what tool should be used with it... I don't recognize that syntax.

Comment: Each line is supposed to represent a single rule

Comment: There aren't enough colons or equals signs for that to be a makefile.  The square brackets are not a normal part of a makefile. The lines are all jumbled up.  It is not a regular makefile.  Go back to your supplier and ask for the 'real deal' on a makefile, or an explanation of how that can be used.  We can't supply the information — it isn't recognizable as a makefile.

Comment: Apparently, [`pmake` is a thing](http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/pmake.1.html), so, given that the file is called `pMakefile`, you may be looking for this program?

Comment: @MadScientist You're right it doesn't look like a makefile. I have to parse each line . Would I be able to use each line as a single command somehow?

Comment: @Nahim No, there are some rules which are split across multiple lines. The first two lines make up a single rule, for example.

Comment: @ForceBru, I made a similar leap and checked out `pmake`, but all the documentation I found suggested that it uses standard makefile syntax.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, yeah, I couldn't find any mention of the syntax with the square brackets either...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a standard Makefile, but I think I see how it could be converted into one. On each line, the first filename is the target, subsequent filenames are dependencies, and the text in brackets is the rule.

For example, the first two lines:

```
wombat aardvark.o manatee.o penguin.o velociraptor.o wombat.o [gcc -o 
wombat aardvark.o manatee.o penguin.o velociraptor.o wombat.o]
```

would be represented in a Makefile as:

```
wombat: aardvark.o manatee.o penguin.o velociraptor.o wombat.o
    gcc -o wombat aardvark.o manatee.o penguin.o velociraptor.o wombat.o
```

Even with that fixed, though, this is a very poorly written Makefile -- it makes no use of basic features like variables or wildcard rules, making it highly repetitive. You'd really be better off rewriting it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The code presented does not constitute a valid makefile.  I'm not sure what utility is supposed to consume it, but it looks like it is structured as lines of this form:

```
target prerequisite ... '[' recipe ']'
```

In that case, a corresponding standard makefile would be

```
wombat: aardvark.o manatee.o penguin.o velociraptor.o wombat.o
    gcc -o $@ aardvark.o manatee.o penguin.o velociraptor.o wombat.o

aardvark.o: aardvark.h aardvark.c
    gcc -c -o $@ aardvark.c

aardvark.h: aardvark1.txt aardvark2.txt
    date | sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/g' | cat -s aardvark1.txt - aardvark2.txt > $@

manatee.o: manatee.h manatee.c
    gcc -c -o $@ manatee.c

penguin.o: penguin.h penguin.c
    gcc -c -o $@ penguin.c

velociraptor.o: velociraptor.h velociraptor.c
    gcc -c -o $@ velociraptor.c

wombat.o: aardvark.h manatee.h penguin.h velociraptor.h wombat.h wombat.c
    gcc -c -o $@ wombat.c
```